# cancan not working with activeadmin 0.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

I am not beeing able to make this work.

I have a project with activeadmin 0.4.4 and devise working, and I need to include role-based permissions to it, so I thought on CanCan. The roles could be 'administrator' or 'publisher', administrator can manage all and publisher only a post section.

I followed https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-cancan-with-activeadmin, the AdminUser crud it is working fine, and the config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user! was alredy uncomment.

In my ApplicationController I added the following:

```
  # https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/exception-handling
    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          redirect_to admin_root_path, :alert => exception.message
        end
      end
    end

  # https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/changing-defaults
    def current_ability
      @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin_user)
    end
```

And here is my Ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= AdminUser.new

    if user.role?('administrator')
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

The Ability initialize method is not executing. I tried abort, -as the comments suggest- puts or p, and even sintax error and I have nothing. What am I mising?

I'm stuck here, I also tried http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter but it is rising undefined method "authorization adapter", I am not sure if this is working with my activeadmin version. And adding a require active_admin/cancan_adapter rise a LoadError.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure what `abort()` method available in `cancan`?

Comment: thanks for replying.
I supposed it should, I added it because it is not working, with a publisher role I can access and change everything.
Try with puts a get nothing as well.

Comment: there is no such method `abort()` in `cancan` . You do not need call this method in `initialize()` of `Ability`, `cancan` make it for you.

Comment: any idea on how can I be sure the `initialize(user)` method is executing then?

Comment: `initialize()` method in Ruby it is constructor new class instance and call wherever where you invoke `new()`

Comment: ok, but I expect then `activeadmin` to call `cancan` when need it, am I wrong? I can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57655/discussion-between-joseiogr-and-).

Comment: @joseiogr insert any of print message into `initialize` like `p "INIT"`, or if `pry` is available insert: `binding.pry`

Comment: Nothing, I have nothing. I event tried to write some sintax error and there are no complains. I am pretty sure cancan is not loading and don't know why.

Please any other help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did the trick thanks to http://makandracards.com/jan0sch/13877-rails-activeadmin-and-cancan

Basically I need to add a controller block in the activeadmin register page for loading it:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Whatever do
    #...
    controller do
      load_and_authorize_resource :except => :index

      def scoped_collection
        end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability)
      end
    end
    #...
end
```